# Connecting to rpi through wifi

Tags: wifi, ssh, raspbian-jessie

i have rpi with jessie release, i can ssh to it through ethernet as i have forced static ip, but i cant ssh to it through wifi. Wifi conection is configured (ssid and psk) and rpi is connected to it. When i execute in my PC command:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.1/24
```

it finds all devices connected to wifi except raspberry.

I have tryed to force static IP with wifi connection in `etc/network/interfaces` but then i get `no wireless interfaces were found`

i have raspberry connected to tv but no keyboard or mouse are available

`etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
#iface eth0 inet manual
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.188
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.254



auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

result of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:bd1e Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`
```

`etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="test-network"
    psk="testpasswd"
}
```

`ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:66:da:a2  
      inet addr:192.168.1.188  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe66:daa2/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:583 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:422 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:53261 (52.0 KiB)  TX bytes:47466 (46.3 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:243 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:243 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:21778 (21.2 KiB)  TX bytes:21778 (21.2 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:b4:e6:bf:a0:d3  
      inet addr:192.168.1.58  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::feb4:e6ff:febf:a0d3/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:140 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:12631 (12.3 KiB)  TX bytes:9147 (8.9 KiB)
```

Problem got kinda solved, still dont know what caused it but here are attempts to fix and fix:

1. checked if wifi is enumerated with `lsusb`, it was enumerated.
2. in `etc/network/interfaces` changed  `iface wlan0 inet manual` to `iface wlan0 inet dhcp` -> reboot.
3. with dhcp set `no wireless interfaces were found`
4. tryed `sudo service sshd restart` got `dhcpcd not running` info when hovered over connection icon
5. in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` uncommented line `ListenAddress 0.0.0.0` then reboot and try ssh again, didnt work.
6. checked wifi dongle on windows 7 and ubuntu 14, worked fine, changed charger to 5V/2A, but still didnt solve anything.

These steps should have solved my problem but they didn't, so i copied to desktop and reverted all changes made to wpa-supplicant and interfaces, connected a touchscreen to rpi andconnected with graphic interface by copyiong psk from wpa-supplicant on desktop. Everything worked fine. I compared working wpa supplicant and interfaces with not-working ones but they where identical, dont know what caused my problem but using graphical interface fixed it.

Comment: Is your wiFi enumerated by the Pi? What is the output of lsusb?

Comment: how to check if its enumerated? i edited the post with result of lsusb

Comment: To verify it is enumerated remove the dongle and rerun lsusb if you have a missing entry comapred to the above you know that it is being enumerated. I suspect that the first line above is your WiFi dongle. Please add /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf and ifconfig to your question

Comment: yes, its enumerated. added missing info.

Comment: Can you SSH pi@192.168.1.58

Comment: no, when i change `iface wlan0 inet manual` to `iface wlan0 inet dhcp` it shows `no wireless interfaces found`, when its on manual it connects to wifi but cant ssh.

Comment: after switching to dhcp do you restart the Pi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33602/discussion-between-cynizm-and-steve-robillard).

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide what you want to do.

If you want to use the WiFi config in the GUI (which is where the `no wireless interfaces were found` message comes from) you MUST use `dhcpcd`.

If you want to configure it in the old way, disable `dhcpcd` (which is what happens if you use `dhcp`), although you should do this properly.

If you want to set static IP you must do it the `dhcpcd` way.

See the following for a description of how to setup `dhcpcd`.
[How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)